# How to build an instruction to a create metadata account using latest `mpl-token-metadata` library?

Tags: metaplex, mpl-token-metadata

Previously, we could get a `TransactionInstruction` using `createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction` and add the instruction to a transaction.

```
export declare function createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction(accounts: CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionAccounts, args: CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionArgs, programId?: web3.PublicKey): web3.TransactionInstruction;
```

The latest version (3.1.0) of `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata` seems to be completely different and uses Umi. Has anyone figured out how to use this new version and is it required to also install Umi?

```
export declare function createMetadataAccountV3(context: Pick<Context, 'eddsa' | 'identity' | 'payer' | 'programs'>, input: CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionAccounts & CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionArgs): TransactionBuilder;
```

Basically trying to figure out how to do something like the following:

```
const instruction = createMetadataAccountV3(...)
const transaction = new Transaction().add(instruction);
```

How to get a `TransactionInstruction` from `TransactionBuilder`, and how to you set up the Umi context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was the last day of the Hyperdrive Hackathon and I was stuck exactly at this problem. Since, I have worked with the previous versions of `mpl-token-metadata`, I was assured that I will be able to build this part in minutes but Umi came as the surprise and took a good two hours of mine. :D

After playing with Umi for a couple of hours, I was able to figure it out. Not the cleanest of the solutions but it worked. You can improve it as you like:

```
//Imports
import { createUmi } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults'
import { createMetadataAccountV3, CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionAccounts, CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionArgs } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata'
import { clusterApiUrl, PublicKey, Keypair, Transaction, Connection, sendAndConfirmTransaction } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { fromWeb3JsPublicKey, toWeb3JsPublicKey } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi-web3js-adapters'

//Connection and Umi instance
const endpoint = clusterApiUrl("devnet");
const umi = createUmi(endpoint)
const connection = new Connection(endpoint);
const keypair: Keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from(secret));

//Constants
const mplProgramId = new PublicKey("metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s");
const mint = new PublicKey("8Lw2vWmtXbHGj6PYEnRXtFwrnjz2sS7CtoRdHGRq9ndA");
const [metadata] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([
    Buffer.from("metadata"),
    mplProgramId.toBytes(),
    mint.toBytes()
], mplProgramId);

//Metadata Account IX Args
const args: CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionArgs = {
    data: {
        name: "My Token",
        symbol: "TOKN",
        uri: "",
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
        collection: null,
        creators: [
            {address: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(keypair.publicKey), verified: true, share: 100}
        ],
        uses: null
    },
    isMutable: true,
    collectionDetails: null
}

//The tx builder expects the type of mint authority and signer to be `Signer`, so built a dummy Signer instance
const signer = {
    publicKey: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(keypair.publicKey),
    signTransaction: null,
    signMessage: null,
    signAllTransactions: null
}

//Metadata account IX Accounts
const accounts: CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionAccounts = {
    metadata: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(metadata),
    mint: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(mint), 
    payer: signer,
    mintAuthority: signer,
    updateAuthority: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(keypair.publicKey)
}

//Arguments merged to match the parameter required by the method
const fullArgs = {...accounts, ...args}

const metadataBuilder = createMetadataAccountV3(umi, fullArgs);

(async() => {
    const ix: any = metadataBuilder.getInstructions()[0];
    ix.keys = ix.keys.map(key => {
        const newKey = {...key};
        newKey.pubkey = toWeb3JsPublicKey(key.pubkey);
        return newKey;
    });

    const tx = new Transaction().add(ix);
    const sig = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, tx, [keypair]);

    console.log(sig)
})()
```

Answer (score 2):

## A simpler solution, using `mpl-token-metadata` version 2 (no Umi).

`@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata` version 3 duplicates a lot of web3.js unnecessarily and requires learning a bunch of additional concepts specific to Metaplex.

The existing `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata` version 2 is still maintained, and can send instructions to the latest onchain program (which is version 3).

Install `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata@2` (and `esrun` to run our TypeScript:

```
npm i "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata@2 esrun"
```

Then make a file called `create-token-metadata.ts`:

```
// This uses "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata@2" to create tokens
import "dotenv/config";
import {
  getKeypairFromEnvironment,
  getExplorerLink,
} from "@solana-developers/helpers";
import {
  Connection,
  clusterApiUrl,
  PublicKey,
  Transaction,
  sendAndConfirmTransaction,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import { createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction } from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";

const user = getKeypairFromEnvironment("SECRET_KEY");

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

console.log(
  ` We've loaded our keypair securely, using an env file! Our public key is: ${user.publicKey.toBase58()}`
);

const TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID = new PublicKey(
  "metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s"
);

// Subtitute in your token mint account
const tokenMintAccount = new PublicKey("YOU_TOKEN_MINT_ADDRESS_HERE");

const metadataData = {
  name: "Solana Training Token",
  symbol: "TRAINING",
  // Arweave / IPFS / Pinata etc link using metaplex standard for off-chain data
  uri: "https://arweave.net/1234",
  sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
  creators: null,
  collection: null,
  uses: null,
};

const metadataPDAAndBump = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
  [
    Buffer.from("metadata"),
    TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(),
    tokenMintAccount.toBuffer(),
  ],
  TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
);

const metadataPDA = metadataPDAAndBump[0];

const transaction = new Transaction();

const createMetadataAccountInstruction =
  createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction(
    {
      metadata: metadataPDA,
      mint: tokenMintAccount,
      mintAuthority: user.publicKey,
      payer: user.publicKey,
      updateAuthority: user.publicKey,
    },
    {
      createMetadataAccountArgsV3: {
        collectionDetails: null,
        data: metadataData,
        isMutable: true,
      },
    }
  );

transaction.add(createMetadataAccountInstruction);

const transactionSignature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
  connection,
  transaction,
  [user]
);

const transactionLink = getExplorerLink(
  "transaction",
  transactionSignature,
  "devnet"
);

console.log(`✅ Transaction confirmed, explorer link is: ${transactionLink}!`);

const tokenMintLink = getExplorerLink(
  "address",
  tokenMintAccount.toString(),
  "devnet"
);

console.log(`✅ Look at the token mint again: ${tokenMintLink}!`);
```

Then run this with `esrun`:

```
npx esrun create-token-metadata.ts
```

Your token will now have Metadata in Solana Explorer:

[image]