# How to get the transaction object in bubblegum?

Tags: bubblegum

I have been trying to get the transaction, instructions, or anything that I can use to create my own transaction object for compressed NFTs, and whatever I do looks like everything is replicated and not compatible with web3.js library... how can I use bubblegum umi library to get a transaction...?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yea, it doesn't seem like umi is meant to be used with web3.js. You can reference the answer to this question where 0xShuk used `toWebJsPublicKey(...)` to convert the address to web3.js compatible pubkeys: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/7909/how-to-build-an-instruction-to-a-create-metadata-account-using-latest-mpl-token

Comment: Thanks for the reference but I still don't understand why someone wants to create something incompatible with the main library! it's insane, it's reinventing the wheel and not taking into account the work of Solana labs team... Anyway, thanks again for sharing the link!